# C# what is returned in SQL query returns nothing?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, razor, if-statement

I wish to have an If statement in my code, which tests if any results are obtained from my SQL query. I have tried looking on Google but have not found any effective way to test this.

My code at the moment always goes into the If block and tried to display the page. What have I done wrong ?

```
var pendingMeetings = db.Query("SELECT * FROM table");
if (pendingMeetings != null) {
    //display page
} else {
    <h1>No results found!</h1>
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with LINQ-to-SQL but `if (pendingMeetings.Any())` should work.

Comment: Hey Simon, have you tried looking into the object via debug? I have never tried doing it your way but what I would do would be to look into the object. It probably has an object that is instantiated but perhaps it has zero records on it? Look for a Count property or something? Even better, cast it ToList() and use <object name>.Count. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
if (pendingMeetings.Any())
{
     // display page
}
else 
{
    <h1>No results found!</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a resultset with no rows (but will get the column names).

See Bala R's answer for a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your `if` statement to

```
if (pendingMeetings != null && pendingMeetings.Count() > 0)
{ 
    //snip
}
```

`db.Query` returns an `IEnumerable<object>`

Comment: don't do Count() it would have to read all data returned. Use Any()